# Make overflow-auto only for the last part of the page

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a page which consist of two parts: first part can be of various height and the second part should take all other size of the visible page. The height of all elements inside of the second part can be big and only that part should be scrollable.

The closest thing I came up with is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WY4NS/), but the problem is that I am using fixed height of the second element:

```
.images{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 350px;
}
```

One more time: I do not know the height of the first part, so I can not use something like `height: 20%` for the first one, and `height: 80%` for the second.

Any idea, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered fixing the position of the first part?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I am not really sure I understand what do you mean.

Comment: As in using position:fixed for your header and then keeping the content of the body under that?

Comment: Let me know if this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following jQuery code:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
var imagesHeight = windowHeight - headerHeight;
$('.images').height(imagesHeight);
```

Don't forget to include the link to main jQuery in your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You may keep this in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Thanks for programming solution, but I was looking for pure CSS html and that is why I tagged it without JS.

Answer (score -1):

I was put "overflow:hidden;" Property in to body tag

CSS:

body{

```
   overflow-y: hidden;
```

}

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WY4NS/3/)

Comment: This has changed nothing. The height of the second part is always the same, so if someone has huge monitor it looks terrible. The same is if someone has small screen (phone)

Comment: if you have to fixed that screen issue , give a **(max-width)** for **(.images)** class.                                                           **Eg:**                                                                           .images{max-width:500px;}